# Uncaught ReferenceError: WebFont is not defined at

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

Error no1: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  --> webfont.min.js:1
Error no2: Uncaught ReferenceError: WebFont is not defined at

```html
<----View---->
@{
    ViewData ["Title"] = "ViewDetails";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Name: @ViewBag.FullName</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Total Policies: @ViewBag.TotalPolicy</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive-md">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="basic-datatables" cellspacing="0">
        <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 30%">ACCUMULATION</th>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Total NAR amount (basic life)</td>
                <td>@ViewBag.TotalNarBasic</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Total NAR reinsured amount (basic life)</td>
                <td>@ViewBag.TotalRNarBasic</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    $('#basic-datatables').DataTable({ searching: false });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you import the `webfont.js`?

Comment: call  <partial name="_Scripts" /> . i render webfont as below:
<script src="~/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/webfont/webfont.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please share more code bro. 404 means you do not import successfully. 1. Where did you invoke `<partial name="_Scripts" />`? 2. How do you import script in partial? 3. Did you download the webfont.js in local or did you use cdn link?

Comment: Hi @Rena,  <partial name="_Scripts" /> is invoked in the body of  _Layout.cshtml.
<body>
 <partial name="_Scripts" />
</body>
2. yes i import the script in partial. 
3. I store it in the  wwwroot/Atlantis Theme/js/plugin/webfont/webfont.min.js"

Comment: @Rena i was able to get rid of error no. 2. by adding '~' before  /Atlantis Theme

however  still have error 1:   GET https://localhost:44303/Exposure/Atlantis%20Theme/css/fonts.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404    :webfont.min.js:17

Comment: @Rena thanks for helping. it seems to be ok now. I replaced ../Atlantis Theme/css/fonts.min.css with ../../Atlantis Theme/css/fonts.min.css . this has resolve the error.